# Netbeans 8.0.1 with PHPUnit and Skeleton generator

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I have installed Netbeans together with `PHPUnit` and `phpunit-skeleton-generator` from homebrew. I can generate a testfile from the terminal by running `phpunit-skelgen --test -- "UrlDecoder" classes/UrlDecoder.class.php`, however Netbeans refuses when I right-click the file, select `tools` > `Create tests`. 
This is the error I get:
[image: Netbeands Error]

And this is the output from the log:

```
"/usr/local/opt/php55/bin/php" "/usr/local/bin/phpunit-skelgen" "--ansi" "generate-test" "--bootstrap=/Users/paulp/Sites/fortv/tests/bootstrap.php" "UrlDecoder" "/Users/paulp/Sites/fortv/classes/UrlDecoder.class.php" "UrlDecoderTest" "/Users/paulp/Sites/fortv/tests/classes/UrlDecoder.classTest.php"

/usr/bin/env php -d allow_url_fopen=On -d detect_unicode=Off /usr/local/Cellar/phpunit-skeleton-generator/1.2.1/libexec/phpunit-skelgen-1.2.1.phar $*
Done.
```

Most tutorials and help I find online are for Netbeans 7.x, which makes things harder. I have tried with different bootstrap files and xml files, but no different result. The Output tells me nothing, and nothing happens.
I have googled this for a bit, but found nothing similar to my problem.

The only thing I notice is the `--ansi` part, which the skeleton generator documentation doesn't seem to offer.

My question: How can I get Netbeans to generate tests using phpunit skeleton generator?

Comment: I think you need to specify the class with namespace.  I am not using Netbeans, but the PHPUnit generator normally needs namespaces with the classes, if you are using them.

Answer (score 0):

- I've installed phpunit on my Mac manually following the manual's instructions (it is pretty easy so you don't need brew script).
- Then in Netbeans (8.0.2) preferences (PHP->Frameworks&Tools->PHPUnit) I have set up paths to sctipts.
- In the project properties phpunit should be switched on (I know that's obvious). And then Tools->Create tests works just out-of-the-box. :)

However my first experience with phpunit installation was not so funny. So I can understand that users could be frustrated at the begining. It was because I have expected full automation through plugin installation and such things which not worked. That's why I describe full process (phpunit+netbeans on osx)on my [blog][1].